# Convertir un archivo en un arreglo binario desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, file

Hola quisiera saber si existe la manera convertir un archivo / file en un objeto binario desde **js** para después pasarlo como parametro en un **ajax** . Si suponemos que estoy tomando estre archivo de un **input type=file** y que después quiero pasarlo al servidor usando C#. Un Ejemplo estaría increible. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hace poco yo hice eso y te paso mi porcion de codigo, ojala te sirva:

```
$('#myFile').on('change', function (e) {

                 readFile(this.files[0], function (e) {
                      bytes = (e.target.result);
                      console.log(bytes);
                 });

});
```

Esto te va a imprimir algo asi:
**data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUKJYCAgIAKMTEgMC...**

Sin embargo si lo vas a ocupar en un ajax la parte de **data:application/pdf;base64,** no te va a servir de mucho, esto lo puedes quitar con un :

```
bytes.replace("data:" + formato + ";base64,", "")
```

el formato lo sacas con un:

```
formato = this.files[0].type;
```

Cabe mencionar que esto lo ocupe para adjuntar un archivo y poder enviarlo mediante un correo electronico el cual era un WS en JAVA

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentaré pese a que estoy en **C#**

Comment: @Bernardo Ramirez, amigo podrías explicar un poco más la función, la he tratado de aplicar, pero no entiendo de donde sale el readFile